# Google Apps Script with local drive attachment

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-attachments

Can Google Apps Script send an email through Gmail with an attachment from a local drive not Google Drive?  If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to add a file from local automatically but you could use [Google Picker](https://developers.google.com/picker/) to add a user interface to help the end-user to pick a file from local. For details see https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs